# Storing chat logs, should I store it in a database, text file or both?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am currently experimenting on developing a jquery/php instant messaging application. I would like to ask what the best approach is in storing chat logs. I'm thinking of storing chat logs per conversation in a text file then putting its directory location on a database table together with other details of the conversation (e.g., sender id, receiver id, chat room id, etc.) is it even a good idea?

Comment: No, it will be terrible to query later on. Do it all in the DB. If you have to export it as a CSV from the DB.

Comment: Also keep in mind that for some OS they have a limit of folders inside a path

Comment: @chris85 Is there any way to improve response time then? Im worried that using db would result to slow loading of the chat history.

Comment: It should be faster than accessing a text file. Database can have multiple connections. Run some tests and see what you observe.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not safe to store chat log in a file. Some one could can it just by its URI path. I suggest you save it in DB.

Comment: .htaccess <-- deny from all

Comment: Log files dont/shouldnt be stored in web accessible directories. I agree with your last sentence, `I suggest you save it in DB.`.